# How do you read logs on a Tizen TV emulator?

Tags: tizen, tizen-emulator, tizen-sdk, tizen-sdb, linux-smack

Although the mobile emulator works fine for `sdb`, I cannot get it to work for the Tizen TV emulator. I'm running a Tizen 6.5 TV emulator in "Developing" mode on a Windows machine. Neither `sdb dlog` or `sdb shell` is working:

```
$ sdb shell ls
$ sdb dlog
```

Both commands generate kernel messages indicating an error with the smack security settings and some library `libkUEPUser`.

```
[ 2905.222855] audit: type=1400 audit(1645111214.210:236): lsm=SMACK fn=smack_inode_permission action=denied subject="User" object="System" requested=r pid=2598 comm="systemd" name=".wm_ready" dev="tmpfs" ino=18549
...
[reporter] pHandle Error : /usr/lib/libkUEPUser.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[smack-logger] failed to send report
```

How can I access the log messages my application is emitting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer: **You Can't**

From the [Tizen TV FAQ](https://developer.samsung.com/tizen/Smart-TV/FAQ/FAQ.html)

> This section lists limitations you might encounter while working with
> a Tizen TV emulator or a Samsung Smart TV. Common issues
>
> ```
> sdb shell is not available
> Cannot check the log messages
> Cannot use debug mode
> ```

You can disable SMACK with a kernel flag in the QEMU startup, but I haven't been able to get it to completely boot after doing so.

**Probably best to use a different logger than the Tizen logger.**

Serilog works fine for my use case; its debug sink can at least send messages to the Visual Studio console.

```cs
using Serilog;

Serilog.Log.Logger = new Serilog.LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.Debug().CreateLogger();
Serilog.Log.Information("Tizen TV application starting");
```

[image: Debug output window of Visual Studio 2022 showing the message "Tizen TV application starting"]

Answer (score 0):

if you are developing a web base app for Tizen Smart TV you can use [web inspector](https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/getting-started/using-sdk/web-inspector.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately this won't work for me; I'm using the Tizen.NET framework

Answer (score 0):

Mr. Lan Hunter's answer is correct.
1.There is no way to get Tizen log with the released image as security policy.
2.User can use serilog to debug .Netapp in Tizen project. Step as below:

1. Install the Nuget package named Serilog.Sinks.Debug in visual studio
2. use code as:

```
using Serilog;

Serilog.Log.Logger = new Serilog.LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.Debug().CreateLogger();
Serilog.Log.Information("any log you want here ...");
```

3. Log will be output to the debug output

Answer (score -1):

I tested it on Tizen mobile 6.5 emulator.
And then, I can use sdb shell and dlog ,too.
Just I guess that it may be internal tv security policy.